# How to draw rectangular profiles using x and y coordinate array?

Tags: c#, algorithm

To handle collision prevention, for example, I set the program to issue a warning when near to obstacles. The x and y coordinates of obstacles are put into array.

Now I would like to draw a smooth profile that is like blocks of rectangles.
However, I get slanted lines whenever there is change in y-coordinate.

A small part of the code I used are as followed, assuming the coordinates of x and y arrays should give rectangular shaped profile with rises and falls as x changes, maybe like building a castle with some variation in height y.

```
for (int i = 0; i < Copy_length; i++)
        {
            chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY(X[i],Y[i]);

        }
        chart1.Series["Series1"].Color = Color.FromArgb(100, Color.Olive);

        chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.DataBindXY(X, Y1, Y2);
```

Other suggestions for handling of collision prevention are welcome too.

Comment: what are `Y1`, `Y2`? I am not sure if i understand your problem/question correctly. Could you extend a bit on what your actual problem is and try to describe a bit more precisely what you are trying to do?

Comment: I see you are using a Chart. What is that supposed to do? What will collide?? Charts are for, well, charting, showing data, maybe even animated. Collision prevention sounds like a game. Are really wrinting a game in  a chart control??? This sounds crazy but also very funny..  - Please expand on your aims!

Comment: Y1 and Y2 will give the spread of Y values so that a chart will be drawn up. However, using the above-mentioned, the Points.DataBindXY(,,) will give slanted line, while I am looking for straight lines that are like right angles and stair-steps when y increase or decrease.

Comment: I am making a comparison using the arrays data in x[i] and y[i], to avoid collision of another moving object from the obstacles. I also want a visual representation of obstacles and the moving object. The above is my approach to draw a chart to represent the coordinates of obstacles in the background, while another Series2 is for the moving object. The collision prevention is then checked using the data in arrays against the position of the moving object.

Comment: You could try charttype 'stepline' or you could use 'line' and add the necessary extra datapoints..: Before adding a point with a new y value you would add one with either the new y- and the old-xvalue or the other way around! - If you want to you can insert the extra points afterwards as well by calling a makeSteps function..

Answer (score 0):

You could add some data points to create the steps you seem to want:

[image][image]

```
void makeSteps(Series S)
{
    List<DataPoint> points = S.Points.ToList();
    S.Points.Clear();
    for(int i = 0; i < points.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        S.Points.Add(points[i]);
        S.Points.AddXY(points[i + 1].XValue, points[i].YValues[0]);
    }

}
```

This should answer what the title asks. No idea how that relates to or could help with collision detection..